# "Read" the graphics screen in assembly 13h mode

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Is there a way to "read" the 13h mode screen in Assembly (emu8086)?

What I want to do is draw a shape in the 13h mode (in color A), then have the user try to trace it (in color B), effectively redrawing over the other pixels. Afterwards what i want to do is to "read" the screen to check how many pixels in color A are present. Assuming the user did a decent job tracing, there most be less A-color pixels than those of my original shape, through this metric i would score the user.

Is there a way to check the screen for colored pixels, or do you propose another way of achieving the goal of "comparing" the traces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You draw by writing to memory. Can't you just read it back from the same address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 13h VGA mode in 16b real mode (BIOS/DOS) has video ram residing at address `A000:0000`, feel free to read/write as you wish.

Also you need somewhat more complex algorithm for scoring, because just tracking amount of "A" will not tell you, how much the user spilled "B" over other areas (i.e. user just filling whole screen with B will win, because A=0).

Example of video ram manipulation in 13h VGA mode (TASM syntax):

```
;filename: so_13h.asm
.model small
.code
start:
    mov  ax,13h     ; ah = 0 set mode, al = 13h 320x200 256col mode
    int  10h        ; set gfx mode
    push 0A000h
    pop  es         ; es = A000 (video ram segment)
    ; fill video ram with some pattern
    xor  di,di
    mov  bp,200
lines_loop:
    mov  dx,64
    mov  ax,1010h
shade_loop:
    stosw           ; write 5 pixels
    stosw
    stosb
    ; modify colours to create sort of "dither" pattern
    xchg al,ah
    inc  ah
    dec  dx
    jnz  shade_loop ; write 320 pixels with different shades
    ; write 200 lines
    dec  bp
    jnz  lines_loop
    ; read pixel back example
    mov  di,(13*320 + 56) ; read pixel from [x, y] = [56, 13]
    mov  al,es:[di]
    ; here AL = 16h (colour of pixel at [56, 13] position)
    ; wait for any key
    xor  ax,ax
    int  16h
    ; restore text mode
    mov  ax,3       ; ah = 0, al = 3 (text mode 80x25)
    int  10h
    ; terminate code
    mov  ah,4Ch
    int  21h
end start
```

To build+run under dosbox I used:

```
tasm so_13h.asm
tlink /x so_13h.obj
so_13h.exe
```

---

edit: there is also BIOS service for [`int 10h` "Read Graphics Pixel at Coordinates"](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-d.html):

> input:
>
> ```
> AH = 0D
> BH = page number, see VIDEO PAGES
> CX = column number (zero based)
> DX = row number (zero based)
> ```
>
> on return:
>
> ```
> AL = color of pixel read
> ```

But generally the BIOS services are very slow due to performance hit of the `int` call itself, plus the BIOS must calculate offset of each pixel again from scratch, while for example your "evaluate tracking" can use some "expected screen" buffer to compare the pixels consecutively reusing the offset of previous to reach the next one, avoiding excessive calculations.

So you should rather try to produce something similar to the way how I'm filling up the screen in the example, processing pixels in "batch".

Even reading optimized to be word (two pixels) vs byte (one pixel) did help on real HW back in 386 era, but that's probably overcomplicating your task, JFYI that even such subtle details did made difference back then.

---

edit2: about scoring algorithm:

Depends how exactly you want to score, but you can do this:

- have original "A" buffer in memory
- calculate amount of "A" on screen = toPaint
- let user draw with "B"
- calculate amount of "A" on screen = notPaint
- calculate "B" from screen over "0" in buffer = overPaintL1
- re-run inside of internal buffer [0,0]..[maxX-2,,maxY-2] and change each pixel to "A" if there is "A" on right or bottom side of current pixel = this will make "A" shape thicker (maybe run twice-thrice to cover +-2 or +-3 pixels off)
- calculate "B" over 0 in buffer = overPaintL2
- make "A" thicker one more time
- calculate "B" over 0 in buffer = overPaintL3

Now final score may be something like:

score = w0 * (toPaint - notPaint) + w1 * overPaintL1 + w2 * overPaintL2 + w3 * overPaintL3

where w0..w3 are "weights" of bonus/malus, w0 should be strongest, as that's the amount of pixel-perfect the user did draw (like 50 ... also each missed A pixels is -50 then), w1 should be very small malus, like -1 (that's just 1 pixel off), w2 may be something like -5 (2 pixels off), w3 may be something like -10 (pixels completely off the shape).

So if the user has shape of ~200 pixel (square of 50x50 pixels), and he overdraws 184 pixels: notPaint = 16, and basically hits almost everywhere +-1 pix off (creating 2px wide square): overPaintL1 = 200, and sometimes he goes a bit more off: overPaintL2 = 15, overPaintL3 = 35

Then score = 50 * (200-16) + -1 * 200 + -5 * 15 + -10 * 35 = 8575
(perfect score in such example is 50*200 = 10000).

Maybe you will need to re-tune the weights and thickening a lot, but I think this approach can work in the end.

---

edit: one more note about thickening... you must thicken in all directions equally, to make "B" overdraw costly in each direction equally, so my original right/bottom check is not valid, but doing the 4-direction check in single buffer is impossible too. So either you would need to introduce second internal buffer, thickening from one to other, or do two-pass thickening first going forward and extending by right+bottom, second going backward and extending by left+top, or you can draw shape with "A" into internal buffer at [-N..+N,-N..+N] positions to cover +-N pixels around original design.

The two-buffer detecting any "A" inside 3x3 grid in source buffer for current destination position is probably easiest to code.

My original description did thicken the A shape only in left+top direction, so the overdraw on bottom/right would be more penalized than overdraw on left/top.

Hmm... in the end it turned out to be more tricky then intuitively expected, make sure you code it by small parts, and debug each separately and properly, also including corner cases and extreme inputs.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @ArmandoHerrera I added some ideas about scoring and your task, maybe don't read them before you try something on your own, so I don't steal the main fun from the task from you (figuring out some algorithm). :)

Comment: Thanks again, really